# How to stop foreach loop which keeps adding the gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity 3d I have 2 gameobjects tagged as Character. I just wanted to add these two gameobjects into a List named characterList. I tried to do that with a foreach loop as shown in the below code. But then this loop keeps going on endlessly adding these two gameobjects over and over again. How can I make it stop after adding these 2 or anymore gameobjects that are actually in the scene?

```cs
private GameObject character;

public List<GameObject> characterList = new List<GameObject>();


void Start()
{
    foreach(GameObject character in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Character"))
    {
        characterList.Add(character);
    }  
}
```

Comment: are you calling start more than once? you could check to see if characterList is empty before entering the foreach.

Comment: @Mikael this is a Unity 3D question, one does not _"[call] start"_ once or otherwise but rather the middleware does, which is _once_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP:

> But then this loop keeps going on endlessly adding these two gameobjects over and over again.

You have declared `characterList` as a `public` *field* and so it is subject to Unity serialisation:

```
public List<GameObject> characterList = new List<GameObject>();
```

I suspect what is happening is that when you:

- run the game (or whilst editing if your script is marked as `[InitializeOnLoad]`) and the code adds to the collection
- you make changes directly from the Editor

...Unity will persist the changes for the next run, resulting in the 2 added from the prior run plus 2 more for the current execution.  This will increase logarithmically per run.

An easy fix is to define your field as `private` like so:

```
private List<GameObject> characterList = new List<GameObject>();
```

Unity will then ignore it and won't attempt to serialise it nor will it show the member in the Editor thus avoiding accidental adds.